# My available ram is only half of what is installed

Tags: memory

So I noticed a decrease in performance, so I checked my task manager to see what's to be the problem and what I noticed is I only have access to 4GB ish of ram, which I found odd because I have 8 GB installed. should I have like at least 6 GB of ram available? And my Windows 10 is 64 Bit so it should detect my ram no problem, and it's a single corsair ram stick.

[image]

Comment: Run hardware diagnostics for your machine and see if hardware (motherboard and memory both) are working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates you have 8 GB of memory installed, 4 GB is currently available for immediate use, and you are using 2.8 GB of memory.  Likewise, 1 GB of that 8 GB is hardware reserved, everything in that screenshot indicates your system is working exactly the way it should.  What exactly do you find odd about that memory usage?  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your system.
You have 8 GB of RAM of which 1 GB is unusable because it is "hardware reserved" (which means that that RAM space is used for embedded graphics and memory buffers needed by various PCI/PCIe devices).
That leaves 7 GB for use by Windows.
That is shown in the left-border under the memory heading as 3.0/7.0: 3 GB used out of 7 GB.
That leaves 4.0 GB "available" and that is exactly as shown.